# How to show commit hash as hyperlink in jenkins console output?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson, automated-deploy

Repository URL: `https://github.com/abc/repo.git`

I am setting up a Repository Browser for this in Jenkins as `https://github.com/abc/repo`

My Console Output is shown as below:

```
Checking out Revision bb8ba2453161dc640ce169b5c794d94ebb9ab318 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f bb8ba2453161dc640ce169b5c794d94ebb9ab318 # timeout=10
```

Even after adding "Repository Browser", the commit hash is not showing as hyperlink.

What can be done to ensure that `"bb8ba2453161dc640ce169b5c794d94ebb9ab318" shows as a hyperlink` in the console output?

Comment: Why not add it by yourself as a link (with your own customization) to the build log?